# How to stop Media Player when you have more that one sound being played?

Tags: android, audio, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

My app is a music pad, which allows the user to create their own music by pressing buttons that will play a specific sound, and if the users presses more than one button there will be more sounds being played at the same time.

**I want to stop all sounds when the onPause() gets called**. But I realized that if I have more than one sound being played by the same Media player Object it only stops the last sound that was attributed to it, and the others stay on playing.

It would be very unpleasant for the user to receive a call and having my app sounds still on playing :p

Any help would be appreciated.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    try {
        while (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
       }
    }catch (IllegalStateException e){

//Do nothing

      }

    }
```

**EDIT**

I tried to implement SoundPool API but since my app is very dynamic (users can upload their samples and also record using mic). And I have everything already implemented and working well, it would be a mess to change it now to another API rather than MediaPlayer. **Is there any way to stop all sounds that were attributed to the MediaPlayer object and that are currently being played? maybe accessing to some other classes and using other methods to stop all the sounds?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few research and trial and error there is no way that I discovered to stop all sounds being played by the same [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) Object, you can only control the last sound being attributed to it, all the other will continue until they end or the app gets destroyed.

Ok so what I did was:

I created an object for each key sound of my music pad, and Override the onPause() with the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();


    if (mAudioManager.isMusicActive()){
        for (MediaPlayer aMMediaPlayer : mMediaPlayer) {
            if (aMMediaPlayer != null) {
                try {
                    if (aMMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        aMMediaPlayer.stop();
                        aMMediaPlayer.release();
                    }
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                    //Do nothing
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into the [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) API. It looks like that would be well suited for your task. It allows you to preload sound files and play them independently.

> The SoundPool class manages and plays audio resources for applications.
>
> A SoundPool is a collection of samples that can be loaded into memory from a resource inside the APK or from a file in the file system. The SoundPool library uses the MediaPlayer service to decode the audio into a raw 16-bit PCM mono or stereo stream. This allows applications to ship with compressed streams without having to suffer the CPU load and latency of decompressing during playback.

Comment: Uau! I was not really aware of this API! Unfortunately the current SoundPool API Constructor is not compatible with my minSDKVersion 14. What do you think of creating an MediaPlayer Object for each sound ? then I could pause them one by one.

Comment: According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html), the SoundPool constructor is available back to version 1, but has been deprecated in favor of the `SoundPool.Builder` in 21. If you are supporting prior to 21, you can do this: `if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 ) { mSoundPool = new SoundPool.Builder().setupStuff().build(); else { 
mSoundPool = new SoundPool( ... ); }`

Comment: ahh yes absolutely! ok cwbowron, if this implementation solve my problem I will accept it has the answer. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Thank you for the hint of using this API, but after a little research and implementation, I notice that there are still a few issues related to this API, and that it does not suits my needs. My app needs to be very dynamic, because users will be able to insert recordings from the mic and upload their own sounds, and I've realized that the loading time of bigger files is just too slow for my use. I find MediaPlayer more suitable.

Comment: OK. I think you need one MediaPlayer object per sound file then to do what you are trying to do.